# Reduce Foreach Nesting and Replace With a While loop?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I've currently got a MySQL Script running in a `while loop` which is as follows:

```
$Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM appointments");
    while ($Rows = mysql_fetch_array($Query))
    {
        ...
    }
```

This returns a single row as an array and I can manipulate this as I want, for example:

```
if ($Rows['Reoccour'] == 1)
        {
            $NextDate = date('o-m-d', strtotime($Rows['Date'] . " +" . $Rows['howfar'] . " weeks"));
            if ($NextDate < date('o-m-d'))
            {
                mysql_query("UPDATE appointments SET Date='$NextDate' WHERE ID='{$Rows['ID']}'");
            }
        }
```

This will be placed within the while loop so I can work with the array itself. But I want to migrate over to PDO, and I'm having trouble with getting the `array` Format which I want:

Here is my code:

```
$Query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM appointments");
    $Query->execute();
    $Results = $Query->fetchAll();
    print_r($Results);
```

This produces a multi-dimensional array which is as follows:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
    [ID] => 1 
    [0] => 1 
    [Appointment] => JCP Lucy
    [1] => JCP Lucy 
    [Date] => 2012-12-21
    [2] => 2012-12-21
    [Location] => Grays JCP
    [3] => Grays JCP 
    [Reoccour] => 1 
    [4] => 1 
    [howfar] => 1 
    [5] => 1
    )

    [1] => Array ( 
    [ID] => 3
    [0] => 3 
    [Appointment] => JCP Sign On
    [1] => JCP Sign On 
    [Date] => 2012-12-14 
    [2] => 2012-12-14 
    [Location] => 
    JCP Grays 
    [3] => JCP Grays 
    [Reoccour] => 1 
    [4] => 1 
    [howfar] => 2 
    [5] => 2 ) 

 )
```

What I am trying to do, is to have the `$Results = $Query->fetchAll();` within a setup like the `while loop` I used when using MySQL Functions.

If I want to get the Array Down To The single Strings I would have to do something like:

```
foreach ($Results AS $results)
{
    foreach ($results AS $result)
    {
        echo "{$result} <br>"; 
    }
}
```

But This Returns:

```
1
JCP Lucy
JCP Lucy
2012-12-21
2012-12-21
Grays JCP
Grays JCP
1
1
1
1
3
3
JCP Sign On
JCP Sign On
2012-12-14
2012-12-14
JCP Grays
JCP Grays
1
1
2
2
```

Which has duplicate values. My Questions is:

1) Remove the duplicate Values

2) Perform a `while loop` while using my PDO Api -- But enable me to work with the Array keys as I am when I done the `mysql_fetch_array` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the options `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` to pass to [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php):

```
$Query->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` gives you

```
results = array(
  [0] => array(
    'column' => 'value',
    'column' => 'value',
    ...
  ),
  [1] => array(
     ...
  },
  ...
);
```

Which you can then iterate over.

Comment: This bit work with minimizing the duplicate keys, but how would I step through this array, inserting specific parameters based on the array Key? as Ihave done when I was using `while ($Rows = mysql_fetch_array()){...}`

Comment: Check my update. FETCH_ASSOC is the equivalent of mysql_fetch_array, so results will have the same structure to it (`foreach ($results as $result) { /* $result['Appointment'], $result['Location'], etc. */ }`)